# UISegmentControl do not want fade when disabled

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a Swift 4 UISegmentControl and I do not want it to fade when disabled.

anyone know how to stop if from fading?

tried this suggestion  ... this changes the color ok, BUT is still faded

```
for view in mySegment.subviews {
        view.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
```

tried this suggestion ... changes color of text only for unselected AND it is still faded

```
 let titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
 mySegment.setTitleTextAttributes(titleTextAttributes, for: .disabled)
```

I want to set the color and NOT have the color fade

Comment: Really. I don't understand what did you mean?

Comment: You could try setting `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` instead of `isEnabled = false` this will disable any interaction with the control making it disabled. But it won't fade the control. This would really only work if you were trying to disable the whole control though.

Comment: "isUserInteractionEnabled = false"   works perfect.  It is disabled but not faded.